# Unable to add a comment to PDF attachment in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pdf

Adobe Acrobat Pro 11 is used to open any pdf attachments that are sent via email in our environment.
Formerly, we were able to add comments to the pdf and save it where it would it default to the temp location that Outlook has designated for attachments to any of its email messages. I believe this location to be: (C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.Outlook).

Normally if I (or any other user) tries to edit the attachments and then close the email message with the attachment, there is an option to save by Adobe Acrobat Pro:

Do you want to save changes to 'Server Fault.pdf' before closing?

If one clicks yes, then an error pops up that says:

The document could not be saved. The file may be read-only, or another user may have it open. Please save the document with a different name or in a different folder.

No changes have been made to Outlook security settings by anyone.

What I have tried/checked for:

- Windows Explorer is not even open at the time of incident but I have ensured that the Preview pane is off in Windows Explorer
- Trying disabling Javascript for Adobe Acrobat Pro (edit - preferences - Javascript) –

  - Tried disabling Enhanced security - edit - preferences - Security (enhanced) - clear checkbox for 'enable enhanced security.
- Cleared out the contents of the temp folder associated
- Checked the registry pointing to this temp folder (HKEY_USERS/S-1-5-21/Software/Microsoft/Office/14.0/Outlook/Security)

Is there any harm in deleting this registry key? Would that help or is it some kind of security issue? I

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?  When you say that it formerly worked, was there anything different at that time?  I suspect the problem does not relate to security, but rather to the general problem of modifying email attachments from within an open message in Outlook.

Comment: We are using Windows 7 professional 64bit. There was nothing different at the time. Exact same setup.